# In - App Purchases in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have developed an iPhone Application that has `three Levels`. Those `three Levels` are displayed as `three tabs` in single view.

*The first level is free. 2nd and 3rd are locked.*

I read some tutorials but I didn't get clarity that which type of In - App -Purchase suitable for my application.

Because if I use Consumable The three Levels must be three Different Applications(But I Have 3 tabs in a single Application), If I use Non - Consumable, an application should purchase only once.

But when user wants to `unlock the 2nd Level`, users need to do payment, I have  bit confusionhere, If I want to sale the `2nd/3rd level` to the user, Is those `(2nd & 3rd) levels` must be different Applications.?

Here I want to unlock a tab(i.e; a button which is Locked.). When user Click on the button It should connect with Appstore and do transactions.

If it is successful, that level should be opened.

*Please let me know if you have any source code.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check about In App Purchase.You can refer below reference.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: In the tutorial.., In Managing In App Purchases.. He is Creating a new  app and adding that to plist... But i want to lock my button.. which is included in the application... And he also told that Non-Consumable Means "buy once, use forever"... What i have to do ...?

Comment: It is proper.You have to check all the steps one by one.

Comment: My Requirement is , When user want to unlock the second level he need to pay some amount... According to your answer i want to use consumable with 3 levels... right..? Please let me know I am new to iOS.

Comment: You need to disable next level button,because there is no any option for different levels.I mean you choose Non-consumable at a time or only for one app.You have to disable next level programatically.That is final.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 2 non-consumable products. One for Level2 and one for Level3. This way you can make sure, that your user only pays once per level. And the Levels could have different prices if you wish to.

Comment: Please let me know if you have/know any tutorials (or) If u Have Any Source Code for Non - Consumable In-App Purchase...

Comment: the tutorial mentioned by Gajendra is really helpful.

Comment: In the tutorial.., In Managing In App Purchases.. He is Creating a new app and adding that to plist... But i want to lock my button.. which is included in the application... And he also told that Non-Consumable Means "buy once, use forever"... What i have to do ...?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have separate applications for each level. You need to create boolean values that change based on the user purchasing a level you then need to save them in your app. Also on fresh installs of the app you need to be checking if the user has already purchased a level and then enable/disable the levels based on the values you get back.

Comment: Please let me know if you have/know any tutorials for Non - Consumable In-App Purchase

Comment: This one is the best [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases).

Comment: In the tutorial.., In Managing In App Purchases.. He is Creating a new app and adding that to plist... But i want to lock my button.. which is included in the application... And he also told that Non-Consumable Means "buy once, use forever"... What i have to do ...?

Comment: Non-consumable means that if the user where to try and purchase the in app purchase again they will not be charged and it will be downloaded for free (apple manages this). You don't need to create a new app you need to use the code in the tutorial and put it in yours. You only need the IAPHelper and the InAppRageIAPHelper files.

Comment: On the completeTransaction method you need to be changing the boolean value in you app that enables/disables the button in your app.

Comment: My Requirement is , When user want to unlock the second level he need to pay some amount... According to your answer i want to use consumable with 3 levels... right..? Please let me know I am new to iOS..

Comment: I would suggest creating 3 non-consumables because you don't want your users buying the same level more then once.

Answer (score 1):

2 tutorials I found useful:

- http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

The type of purchase you need is largely independent of the rest of the IAP architecture - you just choose the type you want (as others have said, non-consumable) when creating the purchase product on iTunes connect.